# Get categories from Feed Rss with ruby

Tags: ruby, rss

I used the rss ruby module to parse a rssFeed.

```
File.open(filename,'r') do |rss|
  feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
  feed.items.each do |item|
   puts category
  end
end
```

Whether there are more categories only the first category in the rssfeed item will be displayed.
How it is possible to display all categories?

Comment: From your example it is unclear where did you get `category`.

Answer (score 0):

If your item has category then it should be

```
...  
puts item.category
...
```

Comment: Post your file `filename` (cut it short if it is way too big)

Comment: Example:

    ...
    <item>
     <title>title</title>
     <link>http:// ... </link>
     <description>description ....</description>
     <category>Category 1</category>
     <category>Category 2</category>
     <source url="http://..">ref</source>
     <pubDate>Mon, 02 Sep 2013 00:10:00 +0200</pubDate>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">...</guid>
    </item>
    ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
item.categories.each do |cat| 

    #do something here

end
```